# Which programming languages support TRUE cross-platform interoperability of software written on them?

Tags: programming-languages, interop, cross-platform

First of all, I would **NOT** like to incite any fanboy or flaming wars, like my language is better than yours.

My question is which programming languages support **TRUE** interoperability of software written on them, between the most common platforms (MacOS, Windows, Linux), without that particular software having a high percentage of it rewritten in order for it to work on another platform.

I do not wish to receive fanboy answers. Please provide valid answers, for instance '**Java** supports interoperability between various operating systems, **because** **xyz**' or '**Python** does **because** **abc**'

Comment: Can't tell how your definition of valid answer would exclude fanboy answers... "**C** supports interoperability **because** *\*I said so\**"

Comment: This has no clear answer. Every language that runs on multiple platforms has *true cross-platform support*. There may or may not be OS-specific quirks which the language either fails to abstract properly or cannot abstract. Whether those quirks get in the way of your application and need workaround code depends very much on the application. I don't think there's any non-trivial language that has absolutely no OS-specific quirks.

Comment: Can you provide a clear definition of "true interoperability" so that this question can be re-opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python + PyQt are truly cross-platform because to run an .py script, you need Python interpreter installed in your system, which is all the same on all operating systems. PyQt is also cross platform, and can have a nice, native look in these three systems you mentioned.